# jQuery + JSONP + Yahoo Query Language

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services, jsonp

I want to get live currency rates from an external source, so I found this great webservice:

[Currency Convertor](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=2&WSID=10)

This service is working like a charm, the only downside is that it does not provide JSONP results, only XML. Therefore we have a cross browser problem while trying to consume this webservice using jQuery $.ajax().

So I found [Yahoo Query Language](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql) which returns results as JSONP and also mangae to consume other webservices and return me the results. This is also working, here is an example URL:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webservicex.net%2FCurrencyConvertor.asmx%2FConversionRate%3FFromCurrency%3DNOK%26ToCurrency%3DEUR'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc
```

This URL return JSONP result and is working like a charm, but the problem appears when I use this in my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: urlToWebservice,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#status").html("OK: " + data.text);
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $("#status").html("Unavailable: " + textStatus);
  }
});
```

When I try to run this code nothing happens, and I can see this error message in my Firebug javascript debugger:

```
cbfunc is not defined
```

cbfunc is the name of the container which surrounds the JSON response, but why does it say not defined?

**EDIT:**

This is my new code, but I still get the `cbfunc is not defined`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webservicex.net%2FCurrencyConvertor.asmx%2FConversionRate%3FFromCurrency%3DNOK%26ToCurrency%3DEUR'&format=json&callback=cbfunc",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'callback',
  jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc'
});

function cbfunc(data) {
  alert("OK");
}
```

And the "OK" message is never fired...

Comment: Doh.. stupid me, the `function cbfunc(data)` was inside another function, when I put it outside this function as a separate function it seams to work!

Comment: Why explicitly specify callback as `cbfunc` and have a hard dependency on the existence of that function when you can let jQuery handle things, and proceed normally within your `success` callback as you would do for non-JSONP calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If available, use the `jsonpCallback` parameter in the call to `$.ajax` like:

```
 jsonpCallback: "cbfunc",
```

---

Its description, from the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) reads:

> Specify the callback function name for a jsonp request. This value will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by jQuery.

The docs later go on to say:

> It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling. You may want to specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of GET requests.

However it is **not** advised to make use of this "preferable" behaviour when making use of YQL. Precisely why that approach is not ideal might make this answer far too verbose, so here is a link (from the YQL blog) detailing the problems with jQuery's preferred approach, making use of `jsonpCallback` and so on: [**Avoiding rate limits and getting banned in YQL and Pipes: Caching is your friend**](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2010/03/12/avoiding-rate-limits-and-getting-banned-in-yql-and-pipes-caching-is-your-friend/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was a great blog link. I read what they wrote and tried their jQuery example, but still I get the `cbfunc is not defined` message. I have edited my post to include my new code.

Answer (score 2):

You should let jQuery handle the callback by changing `urlToWebservice` to end in `callback=?`

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because by specifying `callback=cbfunc` in the querystring generates a URL of the type:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/...&callback=cbfunc&callback=jsonp1277417828303
```

Stripped out all uninteresting parts, but the URL contains two `callback` parameters. One of them is managed by jQuery, and the other one not. YQL only looks at the first `callback` parameter and returns a response wrapped around that.

```
cbfunc({"query":{...}});
```

However, there is no function named `cbfunc` in your script, so that's why you are getting the undefined error. jQuery created an implicit function named `jsonp1277417828303` in the above example, and the response from YQL should instead have been:

```
jsonp1277417828303({"query":{...}});
```

for jQuery to act upon it, and return the response to your `success` callback which it never got to do.

So, as @SLaks suggested, remove the `&callback=cbfunc`from your URL, or replace it with `&callback=?` to let jQuery handle things.

See a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BDK46/).

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should give jQuery-JSONP a try: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/

Simplifies everything :)